# C# Exception: Does it have an unique value/identifier

Tags: c#, exception

**Does the class `Exception` have an unique Id or any other unique modifier (GUID,... )?**

I'm logging the generated exceptions inside a backend-service. But my goal is to only log each exception once.

Perhaps an example might of some use here:
The Service has 3 layers:

```
DAL (SQL-Interaction)
        => Exception A occurs here and is being logged into the database

BL (BusinessLayer)
         => Exception A is passed to here but isn't being logged
         => Exception B is thrown here and is being logged into the table

Services (Service Interface)
         => Exception A is passed to here but isn't being logged
         => Exception B is passed to here but isn't being logged
...
Client-solutions
```

**My current solution** (which i personnally really don't like):

> I've written a own exception (inherits from the base class exception). when any exception is thrown for the first time then its being logged. Then its being cast to my own exception and rethrown. Exceptions of type of my own exceptions are nog logged in the database

example (This is pseudo code)

```
DAL - Layer
     try{}
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          // log in database
          // log in logfile
          // Cast to OwnException
          // rethrown as OwnException
     }

BL - Layer
     try{}
     catch (OwnException e)
     {
          // log in logfile
          // rethrow e
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          // log in database
          // log in logfile
          // Cast to OwnException
          // rethrow as OwnException
     }
```

Update: What i'm actually looking for is an Id/unique modifier. I would scan the database for the presence of this id. And if this id isn't present then i would write a record. If its present then it would just be rethrown.

Comment: Why are you logging multiple times in different places? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: If an exception occurs inside the BL - layer it needs to be logged. If it occurs inside the DAL -layer then i has to be logged. But the client solution must be made aware that an exception occured. So i rethrow the exception in the direction of the client so they know something went horribly wrong. I could just log it at the toplevel, yes but apparently the best practice around here is to log in every method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your `Exception` and create a new propertie boolean as "Logged" , when you log the exception you set true to "Logged" and in your anothers layers before log you need to verify if is not logged.

```
public class YourException : ApplicationException
    {
        public YourException () { }

        public YourException (string message) : base(message) { }

        public YourException (string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

        public bool LoggedInLogFile { get; set; }

        public bool LoggedInDataBase { get; set; }
    }
```

In your DAL:

```
 try{}
 catch (Exception e)
 {
      // log in database
      // log in logfile
      var ex = new YourException (e.Message);
      ex.LoggedInLogFile  = true;
      ex.LoggedInDataBase = true;
      throw ex;
 }
```

In your Service Layer:

```
 try{}
     catch (YourException e)
     {
          if(!e.LoggedInLogFile)
              //Log in file
          if(!e.LoggedInDataBase)
              //Log in Database
     }
```

Comment: So i would use my 'OwnException' and provide their the property 'Logged'? And when the exception arrives inside my logginglogic i would test for the property 'Logged' to dermine if it needs to be written to the database?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt create my own custom exception. What I would do is explicitly catch the exceptions I know can occur in the DAL, For example an SQLException. In the BL catch specific exceptions that can occur there, and let the rest propogate upwards.

It is unlikely that your BL and DAL would need to log the same exceptions, seperate them so each of them catches the set they are responsible for, and then rethrow them so the client UI can catch them.

**Edit**

Forgot to mention, make sure when you rethrow to use:

```
throw,
```

And not:

```
throw ex;
```

So you wont lose your stacktrace

Comment: You make quite a good point. in this application its quite impossible for a SQLException to occur on BS-lvl.

Comment: Thats how I would do it.